# javascript in function in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to assign a color blue for these values of i:  3,4,22,24

right now my code is as follows

```
JS(paste0('function(z, i) { return i > 2 && i <  5 || i > 21 && i < 24   ? "blue" : "grey"; }'))
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same using in operator , something like

```
JS(paste0('function(z, i) { return i in(3,4,22,23)   ? "blue" : "grey"; }'))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. That's not [how `in` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This way:

```
JS(paste0('function(z, i) { return [3,4,22,23].indexOf(i) > -1  ? "blue" : "grey"; }'))
```

Comment: `[].includes()` would look more elegant

Comment: it's an option also

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** - I'd like to state that this is not supported by Internet Explorer or Opera, However it is compatible with all other popular browsers. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for further details regarding compatibility.

```
JS(paste0('function(z, i) { return [3,4,22,23].includes(i) ? "blue" : "grey"; }'))
```

**solution 2** -

```
JS(paste0('function(z, i) { return [3,4,22,23].indexOf(i) > -1  ? "blue" : "grey"; }'))
```

Comment: includes() Not supported on IE https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf()` to see if an item is a in an array. This will give -1 if the item is not in the array, or the index if it's found. Using the `~` bitshift operator we are shifting the binary -1 forward to represent false if the item is not in the given array.

```js
function JSpaste0(z, i) { return ~[3,4,22,23].indexOf(i)  ? "blue" : "grey"; }

console.log(
  JSpaste0(null, 4), // blue
  JSpaste0(null, 66) // grey
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) with an appropriate object.

```
JS(paste0('function(z, i) { return i in { 3: 1, 4: 1, 22: 1, 23: 1 } "blue" : "grey"; }'))
```